# The safest time to drive

Tags: mathematics

After doing much research, I have discovered the safest day of the year to drive in America.  Not only that, I have narrowed it down *to the exact hour*.

I compiled a list of all automobile accidents since 1975 and sorted them by day of year, then by time of day.  Next I graphed the results, and I found that one hour of the year had a significantly lower number of accidents.

## When was it, and why does this happen?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://www.cartalk.com/content/no-accidents-0

Comment: Sounds like it to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The date is

> The second Sunday in March

The time is

> 2am - 3am

Because

> no time elapses due to [daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States)

There *were* accidents reported, because

> As Tony mentioned in comments, some states observe(d) it differently/not at all, plus DST is wonky in general.

Comment: Correct answer, but can you tell me why there are some accidents in that time period?

Comment: Previously, Indiana did not participate in daylight savings. There may have been other states as well.

Comment: Bingo. <!-- Can I put a comment in a comment? -->  I guess I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> something to do with daylight savings time?

Comment: You're thinking right, but you were 1 second too late.

Comment: *Beats head on wall*

Comment: Give me another try: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29981/im-purple-and-small-what-am-i